# Are there any configuration options for RoR asset packager?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minify

Regarding the [Asset packager plugin for RoR](http://synthesis.sbecker.net/pages/asset_packager).

Is there a way to configure it, so that it packages JS/CSS files in development environment, but without minifying the JS files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like it, but it's easy to add:

1. Add "development" env at [this line](https://github.com/sbecker/asset_packager/blob/master/lib/synthesis/asset_package.rb#L15) or setup another ENV variable and if it exists it can be included automatically so you don't mess around with code more than once.
2. For the compressed_file method (which compresses the js and css) you could [add an option](https://github.com/sbecker/asset_packager/blob/master/lib/synthesis/asset_package.rb#L148) (or have it read from the ENV) and compress or not depending on it

Comment: This is as close as it comes. BTW, I didn't know you could link to a specific line in github code. nice.

Answer (score 0):

No.

```
def javascript_include_merged(*sources)
```

It only expects sources and does not have an options hash like most methods that accept options do.